# Turn on Blinking of LED when the android device is in shutdown state

Tags: android, embedded-linux, led, qualcomm

On my Android device, running on Qualcomm SOC, I can control LEDs ( /sys/class/leds/*/ ) when the device is charging ( led to blue color ) or the battery getting low ( led to red color ), from a user space service ( Android HAL )

However, I also need to do the above color change on different battery states ( charging / low battery ) when the device is shut down and the charger is connected.

I couldn't find a service on the Qualcomm board that runs on low power mode ( i.e. when the device is shutdown )

I have looked at healthd daemon that turns on animation when the power button is pressed but I don't think this will be running when the device is in a shutdown state.

Can someone please point at a service/daemon that runs in a shutdown state and I can control leds from there.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the init.target.rc file, I used "on charger" property to change the LED color and set up blinking timer.

on charger

write 255 /sys/class/leds/blue/brightness
write 50 /sys/class/leds/blue/blink